# Problem importing a library in java (VSCode)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, opencsv

Basically I have to do a program that focuse on reading and writing on a csv on java, since I can use external libraries I thought of adding OpenCSV but even after adding it to "Referenced Libraries" on vscode when I try to compile it it says that the package doesnt exist and I can find information of how to do it properly

[image]

[image]

Comment: You miss to ad the jar to the classpath in the javac command

Comment: How do I do that, Im a complete novice in java

Answer (score 1):

use `javac -cp <path_to_jar>/<jarname> App.java` to compile your java file. This will add the library to the compiler.

if you use `javac` from command line, the settings of VSCode will be ignored.

Comment: @Sabtiago Ramirez. If this answer solved your question, please mark it for more people with similar questions to reach this solution.